# Does number of running pods in namespace cause performance issue?

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, azure-aks

We are facing issue in AKS cluster with java spring boot component.

If we run that pod in one namespace where only 2 pods are running it is competing process data in 30 seconds.
If we run same pod in other namespace where 18 pods are running, it takes 55+ seconds to is completing data processing.

This pod is scheduled to be run in separate node where no other pods are running.

Question: Does number of running pods in namespace cause performance issue?

We tried scheduling pod in standalone node where no other applications are running.

Comment: we are using 1.27.3 K8S version in AKS.

Comment: Tens of Pods in the same Namespace shouldn't affect anything.  I could see thousands causing problems if you were trying to do something like update a Deployment or otherwise interact with the API server, but it shouldn't affect its ordinary performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when there are multiple components running in single name space and **enableServiceLinks** is true the code is taking time to process data.
once we changed **enableServiceLinks** to false code is taking similar time as it was taking in namespace with only 2 components.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you're correct in expecting Namespaces to have no effect on container performance. Namespaces are just logical groupings. You're also correct in expecting Node placement to impact performance.
What I would do to analyze the behavior you're describing is compare the resource consumption during the 2 executions. In general - CPU throttling on the node can cause slowness. Also disk performance - if the data processing involves disk reads or writes.
Also would check if the 55 seconds include the container initialization time. If running on a totally new node - image pulling can slow down the total execution time.
What do you use to analyze container resource consumption and performance issues?